# SVG filter "Turbulence" not rendering well on safari

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-animate, svg-filters

I'm trying to apply a svg "Turbulence" filter on an image on my website.
The thing is that it looks well on FireFox and Chrome :

[image]

But looks horrible on safari :

[image]

It seems that Safari is "spliting" my image into tiles... Do you have any idea ?

here's my code :

```html
<svg>
     <filter id="turbulence" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
            <feTurbulence
              id="sea-filter"
              numOctaves="3"
              seed="2"
              baseFrequency="0.02 0.05"
            ></feTurbulence>
            <feDisplacementMap
              scale="20"
              in="SourceGraphic"
            ></feDisplacementMap>
            <animate
              xlinkHref="#sea-filter"
              attributeName="baseFrequency"
              dur="120s"
              keyTimes="0;0.5;1"
              values="0.02 0.06;0.04 0.08;0.02 0.06"
              repeatCount="indefinite"
            />
      </filter>
</svg>

<div className={styles.sea} style={{ background: `url(${sea})` }}></div>
```

CSS :

```css
.sea {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("../../assets/images/Hero/Sea/sea.webp");
  background-size: cover;
  filter: url("#turbulence");
  animation: floating 80s ease forwards infinite;
  transform: translateY(0) scale(1.25);
}
```

I tried to remove my animation and my transform but it doesn't work...

Thanks by advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Safari: when a turbulence is transformed, it loses its tile-stitching. Take off the transform: scale(1.2) and it works fine in desktop Safari at least.

Hygiene tip - always add color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" to an SVG filter so you don't trigger one of Safari's many bugs in the default linearRGB color-space.